# How to redirect after a certain amount of time if the page is not fully loaded yet?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### Problem:

I'm having a video on the start page that is quite slow to load if the network connection is bad. So I want to redirect the user if the page didn't load after x seconds. I'm using Next JS / React.
`"next": "^12.3.1"`
`"react": "^18.2.0"`

### What I've tried:

Using `useEffect` and `setTimeout` to measure the loading time.
The problem with the below is that it's not considering the initial page load or refresh. It seems only to start counting when the component is initialized not when the user clicked on refresh. My "/" page is a server-side page and the component within is a client component in this case I'm not using the app router. With the below the redirect is firing after more than 35 seconds when I limit my network speed to "Fast 3G" within the browser.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // On slow internet forward to work page after 6 seconds
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("6 seconds have passed!");
      // if (document.readyState === "complete") {
      //   console.log("document.readyState", document.readyState);
      //   console.log("site loaded");
      // } else {
      console.log("site not loaded");
      router.push("/work");
      // }
    }, 6000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);
```

### What I'm looking for:

A way to redirect the user if the full page didn't load after x second.

Comment: The page might be downloading the video as a requirement to render the page. Try adding `preload='none'` to your video tag (`<video src="..." preload="none" ...`) to disable this behavior.

Comment: which version of nextjs u are using? and how do you pass data from server to client?

Comment: That's an interesting tip but it seems like the main.js and index.js is also taking 10 sec + in development mode set to Fast 3G. So I tried to set this value but it's still a way to slow redirect. Also it seems to still wait for the video to load. `    <motion.video
      preload="none"
      className={styles.fullScreenVideo}
      playsInline
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
      transition={{ ease: "easeInOut", duration: 2 }}
      autoPlay
      muted
      loop
    >`

Comment: @BenjaminK do u pregenerate data with `getServerSideProps` ?

Comment: I added the Next JS version to my question. So it seems to be my debugging got much better at the moment with testing the setInterval after the deployment. It seems to be that in local development it's not possible to debug this as I received massive delays which not appeared after the deployment. So the `useEffect`is working after deployment. But sadly the document.readyState is saying 'complete' even if the page has not finished loading.  Yes I pregenerate data in the parent component with server side props but it's only loading an array of json data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
  const handleLoadStart = () => {
    window.startTime = performance.now();
  };

  const handleLoadedData = () => {
    window.endTime = performance.now();
    const loadingTime = window.endTime - window.startTime;
    if (loadingTime > 6000) {
      router.push("/work");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <video
        autoPlay
        playsInline
        muted
        src={src}
        onLoadStart={handleLoadStart}
        onLoadedData={handleLoadedData}
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: It's a very interesting approach. I tried it in deployment as it seems the loading times are completely different than in development mode and interestingly the startTime is most of the time `null` especially when entering the URL and pressing enter in the browser so it's instantly redirecting. In local development, the load times and behavior is strange, and sometimes not logging at all. So I'm only debugging now after deployment as it seems more reliable and better to debug.

Comment: Did you use performance API? I updated my answer. So please try it.

Comment: Thanks for your updated answer. This sometimes works and sometimes does not. Depending on how you refresh your browser after manually modifying the URL to "/" (doesn't work) or if you get there by a link from another site or from within the page (works) or use the internal Link component from Next.js (doesn't run). I think it's a great approach but seems to introduce bugs as the `loadingTime` is still sometimes `null` depending on the way the page was refreshed / loaded. Where it directly redirects.

Comment: Also i get this error often `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'measure' on 'Performance': The mark 'video-loadstart' does not exist.`

Comment: The error says that the mark 'video-loadstart' does not exist, which means that you are trying to use a mark that has not been defined or has been cleared from the performance buffer. In that case, you can use the performance.now() method instead of the performance.mark() and performance.measure() methods to measure the time between the load start and load data events. I updated my answer. Please try it.